# delete specific elements from a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Stay home', "Stay home","Stay home", 'Go outside'],
                    'Child' : ['Severe weather', "Severe weather", "Severe weather", 'Sunny'],
                    'Score': ['(Score: 0.0310)', '(Score: 0.0310)', '(Score: 0.0310)', '(Score: 0.0310)']})


    Parent      Child           Score
0   Stay home   Severe weather  (Score: 0.0310)
1   Stay home   Severe weather  (Score: 0.0310)
2   Stay home   Severe weather  (Score: 0.0310)
3   Go outside  Sunny           (Score: 0.0310)
```

I want to delete the parenthesis and `score:` from the score column:

```
    Parent      Child           Score
0   Stay home   Severe weather  0.0310
1   Stay home   Severe weather  0.0310
2   Stay home   Severe weather  0.0310
3   Go outside  Sunny           0.0310
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably better to [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the number:

```
df1['Score'] = df1['Score'].str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
```

output:

```
       Parent           Child   Score
0   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
1   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
2   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
3  Go outside           Sunny  0.0310
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use **re** and *findall*

```
import re

df1['Score'] = df1['Score'].apply(lambda x: re.findall('Score: (.*?)\)', x)[0])

>>> df1

       Parent           Child   Score
0   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
1   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
2   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
3  Go outside           Sunny  0.0310
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.Series.str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.4/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df1['Score'] = df1['Score'].str.strip('\(Score: |\)')
```

Output:

```
       Parent           Child   Score
0   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
1   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
2   Stay home  Severe weather  0.0310
3  Go outside           Sunny  0.0310
```